# iPhone app to read and control other iPhone apps

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, mobile

Could I build an iPhone app with the ability to control other apps? For example to click on certain things in another app while my hypothetical app would be running?

Answer (score 1):

No, you could not. Apple has extensive security protections to prevent apps from taking over other apps. That would be a huge security risk.

Search on "iOS app sandboxing" to get an idea of what I am talking about.

Note that what you describe would probably be possible on a jailbroken iPhone.

Another option would be to use Apple's UI test facility. That takes advantage of the hooks built into iOS for accessibility to allow UI tests to control apps on the target. I've only ever used AppleUI tests on the simulator though, and where I was testing an app I had the signing credentials for.